# gentoo: how delete all config files on unmerging package (from its ebuild)

Tags: gentoo

I am making my own personal package to have collection of usefull programs and configs. Main idea is to emerge this package and have system prepared for my prefferencies. Mainly it works (it simply depends on all my favourite programs), but I have two problems here:

1. how to install USE flags, UNMASK and such before affected programs are installed?
2. how to uninstall it (emerge --unmerge does NOT delete files in /etc, so even after uninstalling the package the USE flags (and others) are still kept - my intent is to REMOVE them, so next rebuild of `world` would NOT use them anymore - yes it means a lot of programs would lose some functionalities like support for some languages, support for some other programs and so on, it is desired result)

My solutions so far are:

1. The package have some files in `/etc/portage/package.*`

   1.1. I emerge that package with `--nodeps` (so the config files are installed)

   1.2. I emerge it again without that flag (so dependencies are installed
   with right configuration))
2. I create (and install) script to parse `/var/db/packages` for my package `CONTENTS` and delete all `/etc/portage/something`  files "manually" and I have to rum this script before unmerging the package

Is there better way to do it ?

Comment: It's more an advice than a "better way" : I would split the problem in two parts : one ebuild for configuration files, and one ebuild for dependencies. Then when installing you emerge first the conf ebuild, then the deps ebuild, and when uninstalling, you do it in reverse order. With this method you control what happens at which time. You still have to write some cleanup code for the conf files in the conf ebuild.

Comment: That is good idea. I can also in the `package_deps` check on the `pkg_setup` for existence of any of that config files and let it fail with message `please install package_conf first` if not found. This way the `package_conf` became installed manually and would require explicitly clean after uninstalling the `package_deps` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just doing/understanding it wrong! (sorry :)

First of all, instead of a *metapackage* (an empty ebuild that have only runtime dependencies) there is other ways:

- use [*sets*](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/sets) to describe your preferred packages. Manage your `USE` flags in a usual way (including per package `USE` if needed).
- medium complexity solution is to write a metapackage *ebuild* (your current case) -- but, you can't mask/unmask `USE` flags anyway…
- if you already have your overlay (obviously) -- defining your own profile would solve everything! Here you can manage everything just like you want: mask/unmask any `USE` flags, define what is *system* predefined package means for you, & etc…

Unfortunately, I don't use Gentoo portage (and `emerge`) and have no idea if it's possible to have multiple *additive* profiles. I have [my own profiles](https://github.com/zaufi/zaufi-overlay/tree/master/profiles/default) here and it [works](https://github.com/zaufi/paludis-config/blob/hardware/notebook/MSI-GP60-2PE-Leopard/repositories/gentoo.conf) perfectly with [Paludis](http://paludis.exherbo.org).

Second, **never** remove any configuration files (config-protected) after uninstall! There is no packages that do that, and there is a bunch of reasons for that… The main one is that user may have them modified and don't want to loose his changes. Moreover, personally I prefer to have all configs that I've ever touched to be in a dedicated VCS repo -- it wouldn't be nice, if someone, except me, would remove smth…

Imagine a real life example: user wants to *reinstall* some package and he has a bunch of configuration files, he spent some time to carefully edit them. Trivial way is to *uninstall* and then *install* again -- Oops! He lost his configs!
Moreover, from ebuild's POV, you have `pkg_prerm` and `pkg_postrm` functions, but both of them are called even at upgrade time (i.e. when *unmerge* followed by immediate *merge* phase). You have to be really careful to distinct that use cases… And what is more scare, having any "hardcoded" (and unique) rules in any package, you don't have any influence on them…

So, please, never remove any config protected files, let the user to take care of them (he is the boss, not a package manager)…

**Update**: If you really want to be able to remove some config-protected files, setting up your own profile looks even more better idea. You can set [`CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK`](https://dev.gentoo.org/~ulm/pms/head/pms.html#x1-15800012.3.3) to enforce **unprotect** files and/or directories. In that way you don't need to modify any ebuilds and/or write an ugly cleanup code.

Comment: Thank you, I will look to the profiles. I am the only intended user of such meta-packages (they are in my personal non-public overlay), so while you are generally right, this is little different case - those packages are just for my own use and I have one for each of my computers, exactly for preserving the precise unique configurations. So there will not be any other user (except NSA and other hackers) of such packages.

Comment: More over I use metapackage for "common-desktop", which is used from that packages (and behaves normally) and if somebody steals and installs `gilhad-hw/hw-nadeshico2-setup-0.0.1-r35` which installs files like `/etc/portage/packages.use/10-gilhad-nadeshico2-setup-kt-deps.use` and then rely on such files, then he have really bad luck, sorry.

Comment: @gilhad, it seems I've found an appropriate trick for your case. Checkout the update...

Comment: With the profile it looks really good :) Thank you, it would make the whole thing much cleaner :)